# Skype button is not visible

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I would like to add the Skype button (https://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/generator) to my Google site.
The code pasted in the Google Site HTML box does not work (not so much javascript works correctly in this gadget), so I have tried with a custom Google Apps Script. I have made a very basic one, but the Skype button is not displayed (only the 'blabla').

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dev.skype.com/uri/skype-uri.js></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="SkypeButton_Dropdown_clandriot_1">
      <script type="text/javascript"> Skype.ui({ "name": "dropdown", "element": "SkypeButton_Dropdown_clandriot_1", "participants": ["clandriot"], "imageSize": 24 }); </script>
    </div>
    blabla
  </body>
</html>
```

(I have obviously added the doget())

Any idea why it does not work?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

What have you added in the doGet() is more important. Can you please post that. You should be doing something like

```
function doGet(){
  var string = 'your html code'; 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(string);
}
```

Remember that despite doing the above, all of your code may not work since HTML code is sanitized by Caja so you should test your code in the [Caja playground](http://caja.appspot.com/) before deploying it.

Comment: Just tried it in the [Caja playground](http://caja.appspot.com/) and it gives the following runtime message. *Uncaught script error: 'Error: not loaded' in source: 'http://cdn.dev.skype.com/uri/skype-uri.js></script> </head> <body> <div id=' at line: 1*